# What happens when I do "cat debian.iso > /dev/sdX"?

Tags: linux, devices, live-usb

I'm creating a live-USB and don't understand precisely: what happens when I copy a file (or even a file system) directly to a device node (as opposed to a file system)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The shell will open the device `/dev/sdX`.  All output of the `cat` command, which ends up being the contents of `debian.iso`, is written directly to that device.

The end result is that `debian.iso` is written byte-for-byte to the start of the disk underlying `/dev/sdX`.

In effect, the device node makes it appear that the low-level contents of your storage medium behave as a single file.  You're writing into this "file", and therefore writing into the storage medium.  This philosophy is known as ["everything is a file"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) and is considered one of the defining features of a Unix system.

Comment: Is this command different from `dd if=debian.iso of=/dev/sdX`?

Comment: @htor, not significantly, but `dd` gives you more control over block sizes, the default being implementation-dependent (eg. 1 or 512 bytes). With `dd` you can potentially choose a better size for your block device, like 4096 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. Does that mean, that by executing this command, I overwrite MBR with partition table and FAT partition on my flash and fill it with ISO-9660 file system with its 2048-byte sectors and bootloader somewhere in? I don't know, how it's meant to work, cause El Torito bootable CD specification allow several modes of action of that CD image - floppy emulation, hard drive emulation and no emulation. Could you also explain, what sense it makes to tell dd (if I use it instead), what size of blocks it should use, if block size is determined by file system (i.e. they must be 2048 byte on ISO)

Comment: @Bob Except with tape drives, the block size you pass to `dd` influences performance, but not what data is read and written. There is no relationship between the `dd` block size and the CD block size or the filesystem block size. A few megabytes will typically give you the best performance, though `cat` can be quicker than `dd`.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks, Gilles. Do you mean, that the purpose of dd block size option is just to influences speed, so its block size is meant to be optimized for buffer cache size or something like that?

Comment: How about boot sector, will /dev/sdX afterwards boot as normal as the CD/DVD image?

Comment: @Bob: That is correct. The block size option for `dd` just has to do with the way it transfers stuff from one place to another and how much stuff it buffers up from a read before it switches to writing.